# Promise rejection works differently between then-catch chaining and then(resolveCallback, rejectCallback)

Tags: javascript, promise

**Summary**

This code represents a functionality that executes an array of promises and returns their *resolved values* in the order they were resolved. It also includes a limiter that restricts the number of promises that can be resolved from the given promise array.

**Constraints**

If the limiter exceeds the length of the promise array, throw a rejection.
If any of the promises throws an error, throw a rejection.
If the number of resolved promises reaches the limiter value, return the resolved promises in the order of their resolution and ignore the rest of the promises.

**Problem**

I have two different versions of the code:

v1 - implements a then-catch chain to execute the functionality.
v2 - implements a then with the resolve and reject callbacks as two parameters.
In the case of v1, the promises resolve without throwing a rejection even if a promise in this promise list rejects.

However, in the case of v2, the code works as expected, i.e., it throws a rejection when any of the promises rejects.

**Code**

*v1*

```js
async function somePromises(promises, promisesToWait) {
  // Throws error if promises to wait for is greater than promises in the `promise` array
  if (promisesToWait > promises.length) {
    return Promise.reject("Count is greater than the number of promises");
  }

  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const resolvedPromiseValues = []; // stores the values of resolved values
    let hasRejected = false; // tracks the rejection

    promises.forEach((promise) => {
      promise()
        .then((resolvedValue) => {
          // Does not execute if rejected. SOMEHOW, NOT WORKING in v1
          if (hasRejected) return;

          if (resolvedPromiseValues.length < promisesToWait) {
            resolvedPromiseValues.push(resolvedValue);

            if (resolvedPromiseValues.length === promisesToWait) {
              resolve(resolvedPromiseValues);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (!hasRejected) {
            hasRejected = true;
          }

          reject(error);
        });
    });
  });
}

const rejectablePromises = [
  () => Promise.resolve(1),
  () => Promise.resolve(2),
  () => Promise.reject("I will reject"),
  () => Promise.resolve(3),
];

async function main() {
  somePromises(rejectablePromises, 3).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
}

main();

// Expected output: I will reject
// Actual output: [1, 2, 3]
```

---

*v2*

```js
async function somePromises(promises, promisesToWait) {
  // Throws error if promises to wait for is greater than promises in the `promise` array
  if (promisesToWait > promises.length) {
    return Promise.reject("Count is greater than the number of promises");
  }

  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const resolvedPromiseValues = []; // stores the values of resolved values
    let hasRejected = false; // tracks the rejection

    promises.forEach((promise) => {
      promise().then(
        (resolvedValue) => {
          // Should not execute if rejected. WORKS AS EXPECTED in v2
          if (hasRejected) return;

          if (resolvedPromiseValues.length < promisesToWait) {
            resolvedPromiseValues.push(resolvedValue);

            if (resolvedPromiseValues.length === promisesToWait)
              resolve(resolvedPromiseValues);
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          if (!hasRejected) {
            hasRejected = true;
          }

          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  });
}

const rejectablePromises = [
  () => Promise.resolve(1),
  () => Promise.resolve(2),
  () => Promise.reject("I will reject"),
  () => Promise.resolve(3),
];

async function main() {
  somePromises(rejectablePromises, 3).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
}

main();

// Expected output: I will reject
// Actual output: I will reject
```

Is there a difference between these two of implementing promises? I read the docs but couldn't find any clarity between the two. Asked ChatGPT, it says the just a matter of readability.

What am I missing?

Comment: You probably have a race – it’s not great to have a function spec that requires you to reject on any rejections *and* ignore any rejections on a condition when those things could happen the same time, as they do with your test case.

Comment: It's just scheduling. Your `somePromise` doesn't actually reject "when any of the promises rejects", nor does any of the promises rejecting actually prevent the `then` callback from pushing to `resolvedPromiseValues`. All it does is wait for 3 promises, as long as 3 promises resolve you could proceed even if one rejects later. Promises are inherently asynchronous, the point is not to make assumptions about the order in which asynchronous things will happen or how long they take

Comment: To achieve what you want (create a promise from other promises that rejects if any of the other promises reject, use `promise.all`

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main differences:

- `.then(a).catch(b)` will handle the errors thrown during the execution of `a`, while `.then(a, b)` wouldn't:

```js
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(() => { throw "bad" })
  .catch((err) => console.log("caught in .catch()"));
Promise.resolve(1)
  .then(() => { throw "bad" }, (err) => console.log("caught in .then()"));
```

- `.then(a).catch(b)` will span over two microtasks: the one from `then()` and the one from `.catch()`:

```js
// The Promises's microtasks will be interleaved with these ones
queueMicrotask(() => {
  console.log("microtask 1");
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    console.log("microtask 2");
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      console.log("microtask 3");
    });
  });
});
Promise.reject("bad")
  .then(() => { })
  .catch((err) => console.log("caught in .catch()"));
Promise.reject("bad")
  .then(() => { }, (err) => console.log("caught in .then()"));
```

While the first difference is probably something you want to keep in mind, your issue arises from the second one. **Since all your Promises are already settled**, when using `.then().catch()` you will pick only the resolved ones and move the rejected ones at the end of the list, and actually ignoring it in your example.